# SSRS page numbers in page footer

Tags: reporting-services

I wish to not include the page number (in the page footer) for the first 10 pages of the report (i.e. page 1-10). Page 1 should read i, page 2 should read ii and page 3 should read iii and so on (in roman numerals).... When it gets to page 11, this should reset the page numbers

Does anyone know of the expression I can use to achieve this. So if GlobalPage number = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 do not display, or compensate the globals page number for something else.....Is this possible.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually change the value i.e. putting something similar to the following in the footer:

```
IIf(Globals!PageNumber=1, "i", ...
```

Alternativally you could use a user function try [VBA for number to roman numeral](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184657)

Comment: hi @jason :glhs solution to include a small VB function to specify your logic will be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

We'll do ths with some custom code to keep flexibility. [Microsoft have some code to do the Roman numeral conversion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184657) so we'll adapt this.

Let's add the custom code we need: one function to convert an integer to a Roman numeral and one function to work out what sort of numeral to provide.

```
Function PageNumber(page As Integer, startArabic As Integer) As String
  If page <= startArabic Then
    PageNumber = IntegerToRoman(page)
  Else
    PageNumber = (page - startArabic).ToString()
  End If
End Function

Function IntegerToRoman (ByVal N As Integer) As String
  Const Digits = "ivxlcdm" 
  Dim I As Integer
  Dim Digit As Integer
  Dim Temp As String 

  I = 1 
  Temp = "" 

  Do While N > 0 
    Digit = N Mod 10 
    N = N \ 10 
    Select Case Digit 
      Case 1 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 2 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 3 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 4 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I, 2) & Temp 
      Case 5 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I + 1, 1) & Temp 
      Case 6 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I + 1, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 7 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I + 1, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 8 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I + 1, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Temp 
      Case 9 
        Temp = Mid(Digits, I, 1) & Mid(Digits, I + 2, 1) & Temp 
    End Select 

    I = I + 2 
  Loop 

  IntegerToRoman = Temp 

End Function
```

To make the report more flexible, we'll add a parameter for when to revert to Arabic numerals (in case we need more than ten Roman numerals at some stage when the report gets longer). Let's call that `@StartArabic` and it will be an integer with the default value of `10`. So now our page number expression is simply:

```
="Page " & Code.PageNumber(Globals!PageNumber, Parameters!StartArabic.Value)
```