# Expression for roman numerals in page numbering

Tags: reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSRS page numbers in page footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899447/ssrs-page-numbers-in-page-footer)

This is my expression which works.

```vb
=Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "1", "i " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "2", "ii " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "3", "iii " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "4", "iv " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "5", "v " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "6", "vi " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "7", "vii " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "8", "ix " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "9", "ix " ,nothing 
     & Iif(Globals!PageNumber = "10", "x " ,Globals!PageNumber 
     OrElse Iif(Globals!PageNumber >=11, Globals!PageNumber,Globals!PageNumber)))))))))))
```

*However*, after page 10 I want to dsiplay all pages that follow as normal global page numbers, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Is this possible? The expression above seems to loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa337127%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) should make this a lot easier:

```
switch(Globals!PageNumber = 1, "i",
       Globals!PageNumber = 2, "ii",
       ...
       Globals!PageNumber > 10, Globals!PageNumber)
```

Comment: much easier....thankyou. I reset the page number after the last rectangle in the report, and now reset to numeric form...much easdier. Thanks

Comment: actually not working, just noticed after page 9 it goes back to page (i) not page 1 or page 10 (in numeric form).... This was the final expression used

Comment: =switch(Globals!PageNumber = 1, "i",
       Globals!PageNumber = 2, "ii", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 3, "iii", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 4, "iv", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 5, "v", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 6, "vi", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 7, "vii", 
       Globals!PageNumber = 8, "viii",                 
       Globals!PageNumber >=  9, Globals!PageNumber)